# Passing multiple objects into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

I'm currently working on the last FreeCodeCamp intermediate algorithm and I'm running into a problem pushing multiple objects into an array. I'm passing the first test which is an argument with a single object inside of an array, but I'm failing the second test where I need to return multiple objects from the array arguments passed into it with three objects. I'm only returning the last object in the array

```
[ { name: 'moon', orbitalPeriod: 2377399 } ];
```

I believe I have everything set up correctly. Here's a description of the problem:

> Intermediate Algorithm Scripting: Map the Debris
>
> Return a new array that transforms the elements' average altitude into their orbital periods (in seconds).
>
> The array will contain objects in the format {name: 'name', avgAlt: avgAlt}.
>   You can read about orbital periods on Wikipedia.
>   The values should be rounded to the nearest whole number. The body being orbited is Earth.
>   The radius of the earth is 6367.4447 kilometers, and the GM value of earth is 398600.4418 km3s-2.
>
> T = 2*pi*sqrt(r^3/GM) where r = earthRadius+avgAlt, which is the distance from midpoint of the earth to the object, and T = Orbital Period

So all of my math seems to be correct. T, which is the orbital period I'm trying to return is returning the value I'm expecting. My problem, I believe, is that I'm assigning a new value to my `satelliteObject` object where I removed the `avgAlt` as instructed and added the `orbitalPeriod` calc into `satelliteObject`, but it's only being added to the last value of the second test.

My code:

```
function orbitalPeriod(arr) {
  const GM = 398600.4418;
  const earthRadius = 6367.4447;
  let satelliteObject;
  let satObjectValue;
  let orbitalArr = [];

  const mapObjects = Object.entries(arr.map(item => item));

  for (let values in mapObjects) {
      satelliteObject = arr[values];
      satObjectValue = satelliteObject.avgAlt;
      delete satelliteObject.avgAlt;
  }

  const radius = earthRadius + satObjectValue;

//T = Orbital Period
  const T = Math.round(2 * Math.PI * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(radius, 3)/GM));
  Object.assign(satelliteObject, { orbitalPeriod: T });

  orbitalArr.push(satelliteObject);
  return orbitalArr;    
}
```

Here are the tests:

1. orbitalPeriod([{name : "sputnik", avgAlt : 35873.5553}]) should return [{name: "sputnik", orbitalPeriod: 86400}].
2. orbitalPeriod([{name: "iss", avgAlt: 413.6}, {name: "hubble", avgAlt: 556.7}, {name: "moon", avgAlt: 378632.553}]) should return [{name : "iss", orbitalPeriod: 5557}, {name: "hubble", orbitalPeriod: 5734}, {name: "moon", orbitalPeriod: 2377399}]

So I'm passing test 1 above, but I'm only getting the last object of the array correct in test 2.

I'm not quite sure how to pass the Object.assign multiple times. I tried with passing this inside a for in loop after const T was declared and pushing the orbitalPeriod inside of that loop but I'm only getting an empty array:

```
for (let values in orbitalArr) {
    orbitalArr[values] = Object.assign(satelliteObject, { orbitalPeriod: T });
    orbitalArr.push(satelliteObject);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function orbitalPeriod(arr) {
  const GM = 398600.4418;
  const earthRadius = 6367.4447;


  return arr.map(item => {
      let T = Math.round(2 * Math.PI * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(earthRadius + item.avgAlt, 3)/GM));
      return {name:item.name, orbitalPeriod:T}
  });   
}
                                            
console.log(orbitalPeriod([{name: "iss", avgAlt: 413.6}, {name: "hubble", avgAlt: 556.7}, {name: "moon", avgAlt: 378632.553}, {name : "sputnik", avgAlt : 35873.5553}]))
```

You can solve it by returning the mapped array. Array.map(item => {}) returns a new array that is transformed based on the arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function orbitalPeriod(arr) {
  var GM = 398600.4418;
  var earthRadius = 6367.4447;
  for(let item of arr){
    item.orbitalPeriod=Math.round(Math.sqrt( Math.pow(item.avgAlt+earthRadius,3)/ GM)*2*Math.PI);
    delete item.avgAlt;
  }
  return arr;
}
```